# Remove duplicate array objects mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, duplicates

I have an array and it contains duplicate values in BOTH the ID's, is there a way to remove one of the duplicate array item?

```
userName: "abc",
_id: 10239201141,
rounds:
   [{
      "roundId": "foo",
      "money": "123
   },// Keep one of these
   {// Keep one of these
      "roundId": "foo",
      "money": "123
   },
   {
      "roundId": "foo",
      "money": "321 // Not a duplicate.
   }]
```

I'd like to remove one of the first two, and keep the third because the id and money are not duplicated in the array.

Thank you in advance!

Edit I found:

> db.users.ensureIndex({'rounds.roundId':1, 'rounds.money':1}, {unique:true, dropDups:true})

This doesn't help me. Can someone help me? I spent hours trying to figure this out.

The thing is, I ran my node.js website on two machines so it was pushing the same data twice. Knowing this, the duplicate data should be 1 index away. I made a simple for loop that can detect if there is duplicate data in my situation, how could I implement this with mongodb so it removes an array object AT that array index?

```
for (var i in data){
    var tempRounds = data[i]['rounds'];
    for (var ii in data[i]['rounds']){
        var currentArrayItem = data[i]['rounds'][ii - 1];
        if (tempRounds[ii - 1]) {
            if (currentArrayItem.roundId == tempRounds[ii - 1].roundId && currentArrayItem.money == tempRounds[ii - 1].money) {
                console.log("Found a match");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the full document structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregation framework to compute a deduplicated version of each document:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$stats" },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "stats" : { "$addToSet" : "$stats" } } }, // use $first to add in other document fields here
    { "$out" : "some_other_collection_name" }
])
```

Use `$out` to put the results in another collection, since aggregation cannot update documents. You can use `db.collection.renameCollection` with `dropTarget` to replace the old collection with the new deduplicated one. Be sure you're doing the right thing before you scrap the old data, though.

Warnings:

1: This does not preserve the order of elements in the `stats` array. If you need to preserve order, you will have retrieve each document from the database, manually deduplicate the array client-side, then update the document in the database.

2: The following two objects won't be considered duplicates of each other:

```
{ "id" : "foo", "price" : 123 }
{ "price" : 123, "id" : foo" }
```

If you think you have mixed key orders, use a `$project` to enforce a key order between the `$unwind` stage and the `$group` stage:

```
{ "$project" : { "stats" : { "id_" : "$stats.id", "price_" : "$stats.price" } } }
```

Make sure to change `id -> id_` and `price -> price_` in the rest of the pipeline and rename them back to `id` and `price` at the end, or rename them in another `$project` after the swap. I discovered that, if you do not give different names to the fields in the project, it doesn't reorder them, even though key order is meaningful in an object in MongoDB:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "a" : { "x" : 1, "y" : 2 } })
> db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "a" : { "y" : "$a.y", "x" : "$a.x" } } }
])
{ "a" : { "x" : 1, "y" : 2 } }
> db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "a" : { "y_" : "$a.y", "x_" : "$a.x" } } }
])
{ "a" : { "y_" : 2, "x_" : 1 } }
```

Since the key order is meaningful, I'd consider this a bug, but it's easy to work around.

Comment: Updated my question with the document structure, I don't see what to do with $first.

Comment: Uhhh seems REALLY complicated man. The thing is, I ran my node.js website on two machines so it was pushing the same data twice. Knowing this, the duplicate data should be 1 index away. I updated my question with a for loop I created, how do you think I can use this to remove duplicate data?